# Строку в виде массива с объектами преоброзовать в массив с обьектом

Tags: javascript

Здраствуйте, есть строка

```
"[{\"xvalue\":-426.0,\"yvalue\":6.0280000000000005},{\"xvalue\":-424.98,\"yvalue\":6.0280000000000005}]"
```

Хотелось бы ее преобразовать чтобы получился массив элементов

```
[
  { xvalue: -426.0, yvalue: 6.0280000000000005 }, 
  { xvalue: -424.98, yvalue: 6.0280000000000005 }
]
```

пробовал метод `split()`, но я не до конца понял как использовать регулярные выражения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let res = JSON.parse('[{"xvalue":-426.0,"yvalue":6.0280000000000005},{"xvalue":-424.98,"yvalue":6.0280000000000005}]');
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, примите его, нажав на галочку слева.